# make datatable unchangable but scrollable

Tags: c#, .net

hope you can help me out with this one:

I have a Data-Table where users can enter data, that will be processed later on. As soon as the processing is started (the program controls a machine which takes 1-2 hours to complete) I want to make the data-table unchangeable (so they cant change data while processing is at work) but the data-table should still be scrollable because the list of data is quite long and I mark the row that is currently processed.

I hope you get, what I want to do. I tried

> datatable.isenabled = false;

But this disables scrolling. I couldn't find anything similar to

> datatable.ischangable = false;

hope you can help me out.

Thanks in advance,
Kevin

EDIT: 
Hi everyone. I found the answer myself:

My Problem was, that I tried to make the datatable read only. Now I tried to make the datagrid-read only and everything works fine!

Thanks!

Comment: What type of control are you using to display your data? Is it a DataGrid?

Comment: Yes. The Datagrid displays the information entered.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to set the coloumns to readonly:

```
myColumn.ReadOnly = true;
```

I am not sure if you can apply this at one time to the entire datatable.
You can also try:

```
datatable.ReadOnly= true;
```

Reference [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.readonly.aspx)

Comment: Hi, i tried this too but neither datatable.readonly nor datatable.column.readonly seam to exist. there is a property datatable.isreadonly but this is read-only itself.

Comment: What do you mean with "seems not to exist"? Are you having errors on the line or it does not work as you would like?

Comment: The property datatable.readonly simply does not exist. what does exist is datatables.columns[i].readonly. I just tried setting this one true but now my program crashes with this exception as soon as i try to scroll(sorry i cant get the english one):`TwoWay- oder OneWayToSource-Bindungen funktionieren nicht mit der schreibgeschützten Eigenschaft "MYCOLUMNNAME" vom Typ "System.Data.DataRowView".` Translated by me: `TwoWay- or OneWayToSource-Binding doesnt work with read-only Property "MYCOLUMNNAME" of Type "System.Data.DataRowView"`.

Comment: The exception is thrown in an "unknown source" so I can't find why this is happening.